# How to combine two filtered ui grids into one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, filtering, ui-grid

I am using angularjs ui grid api. I have created a single html input tag to apply a filter to all columns based on the users input. I want to filter each column then combine the results into a single ui grid

I have tried to loop through each column and apply the text filter from the input tag to all columns. This however looks for a row in the ui grid that has the text from the input tag in all columns. I want to display all rows that have at least one column that contains the filter string not all rows that contain the filter string in all columns

angular.module('main')
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $filter, uiGridConstants) {

```
    // ********************************************
    // ui-grid configuration and functionality
    // ********************************************
    $scope.atlasUserMonitorGrid = {

        enableSorting: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        enableColumnMenus: false,

        // pagination settings
        paginationPageSizes: [1, 2, 5, 10],
        paginationPageSize: 5,

        // Dummy test data
        data: [
            {counter: 1, username: 'bob27', last_view: '27/12/2018', total_views: 48, group: 'group 1', data_view: 32, records: 3, crosstabs: 8, reports: 5, explorer: 3, bookmarks: 2},
            {counter: 2, username: 'sarah01', last_view: '04/01/2019', total_views: 8, group: 'group 2', data_view: 2, records: 2, crosstabs: 7, reports: 4, explorer: 2, bookmarks: 12},
            {counter: 3, username: 'jono0501', last_view: '09/01/2019', total_views: 33, group: 'group 1', data_view: 12, records: 7, crosstabs: 4, reports: 18, explorer: 78, bookmarks: 44},
            {counter: 4, username: 'peterh', last_view: '21/01/2019', total_views: 33, group: 'group 3', data_view: 111, records: 12, crosstabs: 6, reports: 55, explorer: 9, bookmarks: 5},
            {counter: 5, username: 'joe201', last_view: '11/02/2019', total_views: 34, group: 'group 1', data_view: 3, records: 17, crosstabs: 24, reports: 128, explorer: 178, bookmarks: 144},
            {counter: 6, username: 'amy_mcN', last_view: '25/01/2019', total_views: 65, group: 'group 2', data_view: 212, records: 27, crosstabs: 14, reports: 718, explorer: 278, bookmarks: 244},
            {counter: 7, username: 'ke', last_view: '15/02/2019', total_views: 1156, group: 'group 3', data_view: 1124, records: 47, crosstabs: 64, reports: 17, explorer: 378, bookmarks: 344},
        ],

        columnDefs: [
            {
                field: 'counter',
                displayName: '',
                name: 'Counter',
                type: 'number',
                sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, uiGridConstants.DESC],
                enableSorting: false,
                enableFiltering: false,
                width: 45
            },
            {
                field: 'username',
                displayName: 'Username',
                name: 'Username',
                type: 'string',
                sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, uiGridConstants.DESC],
                enableSorting: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                filter: {
                    term: ''
                }
            },
            {
                field: 'last_view',
                displayName: 'Last View',
                name: 'Last View',
                type: 'date',
                sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, uiGridConstants.DESC],
                enableSorting: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                filter: {
                    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT
                }

            },
            {
                field: 'total_views',
                displayName: 'Total Views',
                name: 'Total Views',
                type: 'number',
                sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, uiGridConstants.DESC],
                enableSorting: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                filter: {
                    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT
                }
            },
            {
                field: 'group',
                displayName: 'Group',
                name: 'Group',
                type: 'string',
                sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, uiGridConstants.DESC],
                enableSorting: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                filter: {
                    term: ''
                }
            },
            {
                field: 'data_view',
                displayName: 'Data View',
                name: 'Data View',
                type: 'number',
                sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, uiGridConstants.DESC],
                enableSorting: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                filter: {
                    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT
                }
            },
            {
                field: 'records',
                displayName: 'Records',
                name: 'Records',
                type: 'number',
                sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, uiGridConstants.DESC],
                enableSorting: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                filter: {
                    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT
                }
            },
            {
                field: 'crosstabs',
                displayName: 'Crosstabs',
                name: 'Crosstabs',
                type: 'number',
                sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, uiGridConstants.DESC],
                enableSorting: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                filter: {
                    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT
                }
            },
            {
                field: 'reports',
                displayName: 'Reports',
                name: 'Reports',
                type: 'number',
                sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, uiGridConstants.DESC],
                enableSorting: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                filter: {
                    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT
                }
            },
            {
                field: 'explorer',
                displayName: 'Explorer',
                name: 'Explorer',
                type: 'number',
                sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, uiGridConstants.DESC],
                enableSorting: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                filter: {
                    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT
                }
            },
            {
                field: 'bookmarks',
                displayName: 'bookmarks',
                name: 'bookmarks',
                type: 'number',
                sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, uiGridConstants.DESC],
                enableSorting: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                filter: {
                    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT
                }
            }
        ],
    };

    // ********************************************
    // Filtering configuration and functionality
    // ********************************************
    $scope.filterGrid = function(filterValue) {

        // Looping through all columns that have filtering enabled
        // and are of type string
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.atlasUserMonitorGrid.columnDefs.length; i++) {

            if ($scope.atlasUserMonitorGrid.columnDefs[i].enableFiltering == true
                && $scope.atlasUserMonitorGrid.columnDefs[i].type === "string") {

                // setting term variable in the columnDefs filter object to equal
                // the filterValue passed into the function
                $scope.atlasUserMonitorGrid.columnDefs[i].filter.term = filterValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

filterBy: bo
ui-grid

### name     group

bob      group1

john     group2

amy      bobo_group

expected results:

## result

### name     group

bob      group1

amy      bobo_group

## actual results:

### name     group

*** empty ***

This is because the filtering is looking for a row that contains the string "bo" in the name and group column. I want it to filter the ui grid if it has the string "bo" in the name or group column.

Comment: Take a look at registerRowsProcessor() function, and the example on [this page](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20321%20Single%20filter). I think that's what you're looking for...

Comment: Hi Remko, I think that is exactly what I need. I am going to implement it now then I will mark this as resolved with my solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem thanks to the link from Remko.

I have attached the link below for the docs that helped me implement the single filter

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20321%20Single%20filter